# Using a VPN only for a specific mail account or app

Tags: email, ios, iphone

On my iPhone, I know I can set up a VPN. But if I understand it correctly, it is a global setting. How can I use a VPN only when checking a specific IMAP account?

Alternatively, can it be activated on an app-by-app basis? It would be ok if every mail account used the VPN.

Comment: Is the mail server on the private network?

Comment: No, but it won't authenticate connections coming from outside a certain IP range. The VPN's IP.

Comment: Then I do not believe there is a way to accomplish this. Possibly with jailbreaking you can.